# jQuery and cross browser input fields focus handling

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a form and need to be able to highlight/decorate fields as they gain focus (change their background color, border). I'm also decorating their corresponding 'labels'.

All works fine where it needs to: FF, Safari, IE 7, 8 and 9

**Problem 1** cropped up with IE7 and changing background color of drop down box. There I had to resort to plain old JS to access the element and use 'onfocusin' and 'onfocusout' events otherwise it'd take 2 clicks to use the field.

**Problem 2** was with Safari and how it handles 'focus' event with radio buttons. For that I'm using 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events to change the color of their 'labels'.

**Is there a cleaner way of doing this?** The caveats are I have no control of the HTML whatsoever and I can't use anything other than jQuery 1.4.3 That's all dictated by content management system I must work with.

Here's a complete 99.9% 'production' code example: http://jsfiddle.net/HenriPablo/YvDPa/3/

Script in question:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    /* PROFILE PAGE ONLY -> get rid of separator border on shipping addres block when editing any of the shipping addresses */
    if( $('#formShippingAddress').length > 0 ){
        $( 'table#block\\.crmshipping tbody tr td.block\\.crmshipping\\.text' ).css('border','none');
    }

    /* highlight input field labels when input field has focus */
    /* see if event bubble - this is critical for handling decoration of select drop down boxes in IE7 */
    if( $.support.changeBubbles){

        var partialID = 'table[id^="page"]'
        var focusable = $( partialID + ' input[type="text"], ' + partialID + ' input[type="password"], ' + partialID + ' select, ' + partialID + ' input[type="checkbox"]' );
        var clickable = $( partialID + ' input[type="radio"]' );

        focusable.focus( function( ){   decorate( $(this) ); })     
        focusable.blur( function( ){ decorate( $(this) ); })

        clickable.mouseenter( function(){ decorate( $(this) ); })
        clickable.mouseleave( function(){ decorate( $(this) ); })

    } else { // bubbling support check

        var i, d = document.getElementsByTagName('select')  

        for( i in d ){
            d[i].onfocusin = function() { 
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#b4d5ec' 
                $(this).closest("td").prev().addClass('highlightLabel');
            }
            d[i].onfocusout= function() { 
                this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff' 
                $(this).closest("td").prev().removeClass('highlightLabel');
            }
        } // for

        $('table[id^="page"] input' ).focus( function( ){
            decorate( $(this) )     
        })

        $('table[id^="page"] input').blur( function( ){ 
            decorate( $(this) );
        })      
    } // handle  IE7

    function decorate( elm ){
        elm.toggleClass('highlightField');
        elm.closest("td").prev().toggleClass('highlightLabel');
    } // decorator function
});
```

Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The "cleanest" and probably easiest way would be to use the CSS `:focus` selector: `input:focus {background-color: red}`, which is widely supported, except IE7 and earlier.

Comment: that would, but can't happen under circumstances

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if this will do quite what you want, but here is my rehashing of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table[id^="block"] input, select').bind("focus blur", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest("td").prev().toggleClass('highlightLabel');
        $this.not("select").toggleClass('highlightField');
    });
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dg2d7/4/) on jsFiddle.

As far as I can tell, the only thing I changed, behavior-wise, is that the select dropdown list does not have a background color when focused. IMO, it looks better that way, but you might prefer it with the background color.

It seems to work the same on all the browsers I tested, but let me know if it doesn't and I'll look at it and see if I can fix it.